# Never Back to my Previous Activity after new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, back, onresume

I've been working on an application for ordering taxis. 
In the application of driver I have a push service instance 2 activitys depending on the push content. If a call from a customer launches activity 1 if confirmation has been selected to fetch the passenger launches activity 2. Besides activity 2 is capable of launching a call telephone or activity three pressing various buttons, but every time she throws a phone call or activity 3 when returns go back to activity 1

My Manifest looks like:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".RouteActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
   </activity>
```

My Push Service;

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =    
            (NotificationManager)       getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)  
            .setContentTitle("MyTaxi")  
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setUsesChronometer(true);
     if(GlobalPersist.getGlobalPersist("tipoPush").equals("nueva")&& GlobalPersist.getGlobalPersist("carreraencurso").equals("false"))
     {
        Intent notIntent =  new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
        MainActivity.from=1;
        notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        this.startActivity(notIntent);

     }
     else if(GlobalPersist.getGlobalPersist("tipoPush").equals("cancelacion"))
     {      GlobalPersist.getGlobalPersist("carreraencurso").equals("false");
            Intent notIntent =  new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
            MainActivity.from=1;
            MainActivity.carreras.clear();
            notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            this.startActivity(notIntent);
     }
     else
     {


         Intent notIntent =  new Intent(this, RouteActivity.class);  
            //MainActivity.from=1;
            MainActivity.timer.cancel();
            MainActivity.isTimerActivo=false;
            notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            this.startActivity(notIntent);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `startActivity()`, just call `finish()`. This will kill your Activity and allow you to manage your navigation.

Comment: Could you show me where you were calling finish? There's no reason why it shouldn't work.